# How to use word boundary in RLIKE in PySpark SQL/Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use word boundary in RLIKE in my Spark SQL/Dataframe queries, but it does not appear to work.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import * 

usersDf.select('id', 'display_name', 'location') \
    .where(expr('location RLIKE "\\b(United States|America|USA|US)\\b"')) \
    .limit(20) \
    .show(20, False)
```

What is wrong? I tried `\b` too ...

Answer (score 4):

You didn't escape enough.

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([" US ", "FUSS"], "string")
df.where("value RLIKE '\\\\bUS\\\\b'").show()

# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# |  US |
# +-----+

df.where("value NOT RLIKE '\\\\bUS\\\\b'").show()
# +-----+
# |value|
# +-----+
# | FUSS|
# +-----+
```

So it should be

```py
'location RLIKE "\\\\b(United States|America|USA|US)\\\\b"'
```

You'd see that if you check execution plan. Yours

```py
df.where("value NOT RLIKE '\\bUS\\b'").explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Filter (isnotnull(value#33) && NOT value#33 RLIKEU)
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[value#33]
```

compared to correct one:

```py
df.where("value NOT RLIKE '\\\\bUS\\\\b'").explain()
# == Physical Plan ==
# *(1) Filter (isnotnull(value#33) && NOT value#33 RLIKE \bUS\b)
# +- Scan ExistingRDD[value#33]
```

Comment: This works well. Why do we need that many backslashes though?

Comment: @cakraww The target value is `\b`; escape once for the SQL-string literal - `\\b`, but then escape that for the python literal - `\\\\b`.  You can avoid that last one by using a python raw-string - `r'\\b'`.